# Sitecatalyst - success event not defined with evar

Tags: adobe-analytics

What will happen if a success event is not defined with an evar. will that evar get some count.

Comment: You do not need to define an event to exclusively pop with an eVar. It's just extremely common to do so. You can use any other custom or default events and see data associated to the eVar, for the duration of the eVar (whenever you set it to expire). If nothing else, you can use Instances as the metric, which shows instances of the eVar value(s) being popped

Comment: the reason an event is usually popped along with an eVar is so that the event can be used as a metric for other reports